# Extension based on similarity between rational functions and rational numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, rational-functions

After realizing the similarity between rational functions as to polynomial functions and rational numbers as to integers, and the similarity of algebraic function to algebraic numbers, I am tempted to draw a parallel comparison between further generalizations from them, although I am not sure if it will be meaningful and helpful for me to learn some new concepts from you guys:

- the ring of polynomials **VS** the ring of integers;
- the field of rational functions **VS** the field of rationals;
- the elementary extension of the field of rational functions **VS** the
  elementary extension of the field of rationals
- the extension of the field of rational functions wrt some order or metric
  (?) **VS** the field of reals
- the algebraic extension of the above **VS** the field of complex numbers

My questions are:

1. Is the elementary extension of the field of rationals a proper
   subset of the set of complex numbers? Do people study it?
2. Do people study the extension of the field of rational functions
   wrt some order or metric, just as the field of reals being the
   extension of the field of rationals wrt its order or metric?
3. If yes, do people study the algebraic extension of the above, just
   like the field of complex numbers being the algebraic extension of
   the field of reals?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I should say that most CAS (Computer Algebra Systems) are precisely based on all these extensions! See for examples Geddes' "Algorithms for computer algebra" a random extract (http://books.google.fr/books?id=TXfY891RiiEC&pg=PA39) or Bronstein's tutorial (http://www-sop.inria.fr/cafe/Manuel.Bronstein/publications/issac98.pdf)

Comment: What is it that you are calling an "elementary extension of the field of rationals"?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I realize I was being sloppy. I learned about "elementary differential extension" of a differential field from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29). So to make sense, we perhaps need some derivation operator on the field of rationals to turn it into a differential field?

Comment: @Tim: My problem is that "elementary extension" has different meanings, and the *real* problem is that "elementary extension" is already a [term of art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_extension#Elementary_substructures_and_elementary_extensions) in Mathematical Logic. So I honestly don't know what it is you are refering to when you talk about "elementary extension of the field of rationals". Does the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ qualify? $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$? The ring of algebraic numbers? Or do you mean something entirely different?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks for the link! I think by "elementary extension of the field of rationals", I simply meant some field extension that has the results of applying logarithm and exponential to all rationals as members, and has the maximal algebraic extension of the rationals as a subset.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Thanks for the links!